# mat-paginator not displaying data when ngIf is used

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code in my HTML.

```html
<div *ngIf="schemaStatus" class="new-popups">
    <ng-container>
        My grid code
    </ng-container>
    <div class="mdl-grid pull-right">
        <mat-paginator id="paginator{{pageSize}}" (page)="setPagination()" [pageSizeOptions]="pagination.pageSizeOptions" [pageSize]="pageSize"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

In angular ts file, I wrote the following code

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

If I change my `schemaStatus` variable value from `true` to `false` and then `false` to `true`, my pagination shows 0 values.

1. Before I change `schemaStatus` from `true` to `false`.

[image: Before change schemaStatus true to false]

2. After I change `schemaStatus` from `true` to `false` and back to `true`.

[image]

How do I make the paginator show data?

Comment: Please provide a minimal [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with shows your problem

Comment: Please add the relevant component code as well.

Comment: You have to create a new paginator, because it is evaluated after rendering the page

Comment: Is there any way to create a new paginator?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I solved it by changing the the @ViewChild to a setter. This means whenever your paginator will be new initialized the datasource gets the new paginatior.
It´s important to set the *static* propterty to false because it doesn´t exist always.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    if(this.dataSource) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because once the `schemaStatus` gets set to `false`, the `ViewChild` loses its reference to the `paginator` since `ngIf` removes the `paginator` from the DOM. We will need to set the paginator in the component again. You can use a setter in `ViewChild` to set your paginator but this would run in every change detection cycle. So instead you could force change detection using [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) once you set `schemaStatus` back to `true`.

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
// Add other imports here

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    // Add this where you set schemaStatus to true
    this.schemaStatus = true;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-toggle-paginator).

Comment: I tried this but it is giving me error on {static: false}

Comment: Can you tell what is missing from the example I provided? Where is the error and what does it say?